# Night owl AND early bird

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a term that means you are both a night and a morning person in the same spirit as night owl and early bird?

I've seen the joke 'permanently exhausted pigeon', which I like.

Comment: Sleep-deprived?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you **are burning the candle at both ends!**

There was a question specifically on that at

[What does "burning the candle at both ends" mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/151519/131620)

Answer (score 1):

I would call such a person an **insomniac**.

> **Insomniac**
>
> 1. noun form of insomnia
>
> **Insomnia**
>
> 1. habitual sleeplessness; inability to sleep.
>
> (Source: *Oxford Dictionaries*)

As both "early bird" and "night owl" connote the fact that this is the person's habitual sleep pattern, not just a personal preference or an occasional capacity to function early in the morning or late into the night, respectively.

> **Early bird**
>
> 1. (humorous) a person who rises, arrives, or acts before the usual or expected time.
>
> **Night owl**
>
> 1. (informal) a person who is habitually active or wakeful at night.
>
> (Source: *Oxford Dictionaries*